# How can I turn this into a block using a %w array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to have a series of buttons with different values:

```
<p>
  <%= f.submit "Connected", :class => 'button' %> 
  <%= f.submit "Voicemail"%>
  <%= f.submit "Hangup"%>
  <%= f.submit "Not Interested" %> 
  <%= f.submit "Wrong Number" %>  
</p`>
```

Looking at it it seems I could turn it into a do block and pass a %w array but don't know exactly how....?  Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example that illustrates the point :

```
%w[Connected Voicemail].each do |item|
     <%= f.submit "#{item}" %>
end
```

Since this is Rails, don't put this directly in your view, but construct it in a helper.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this?

```
<% button_titles.each do |button_title| %>

   <%= f.submit button_title, :class => 'button' %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: is button_titles = %w[Connected Voicemail Hangup] ?